# multidimensional array, leafs as keys with parent. Recursive iterator

Tags: php

Hello I need to change structure of multidimensional array from parents which contains children data to children which holds info about parents

```
$tab = [
        'movies' => [
            'action',
            'drama', 
            'comedy' => [
                'romance' => ['90th'],
                'boring'
            ]
        ],
        'colors' => [
            'red'=>'light',
            'green'=> [
                'dark',
                'light'
            ],
            'oragne'
        ]
    ];
```

Transfer TO

```
        $tab = [
        '90th' => [
            'romance' => [
                'comedy' => 'movies'
            ] 
        ],
        'boring' => [
            'comedy' => 'movies'
        ],
        'comedy' => 'movies',
        'drama' => 'movies',
        'action' => 'movies',
        'light' => [
            'red',
            'green' => 'colors'
        ],
        'dark' => [
            'green' => 'colors'
        ],
        'oragne' => 'colors',
        'green' => 'colors',
        'red'
    ];
```

I know that for obtaining leafs I could use

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tab), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $key => $value) {

        $result[$value] = $key;
    }
```

But it does not work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very partial answer, so don't get your hopes up. It could maybe be expanded to solve your problem.

For this to work, first you need to `'red'=>'light'` to `'red'=>['light'}` (so it looks like `'romance' => ['90th']`). Then it gives you a series of flat arrays, not with depth as you want it. Also, it is not sorted like your desired output.

```
function insideOut($array, $trail) {

  foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    $new_trail = $trail;

    if(is_array($value)) {
      $new_trail[] = $key;
      insideOut($array[$key], $new_trail);
    }
    else {
      $new_trail[] = $value;
      print_r($new_trail);
    }

  }

}

insideOut($tab, array());
```

This gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => movies
    [1] => action
)
Array
(
    [0] => movies
    [1] => drama
)
Array
(
    [0] => movies
    [1] => comedy
    [2] => romance
    [3] => 90th
)
Array
(
    [0] => movies
    [1] => comedy
    [2] => boring
)
Array
(
    [0] => colors
    [1] => red
    [2] => light
)
Array
(
    [0] => colors
    [1] => green
    [2] => dark
)
Array
(
    [0] => colors
    [1] => green
    [2] => light
)
Array
(
    [0] => colors
    [1] => oragne
)
```

If you could replace `print_r($new_trail);` with something that gives the trail "depth" and then saves it, the problem would be solved.

I know, I know, not much of an answer and I don't expect a green check. But I figued it was better posting my (very little) progress here than throwing it away.

Comment: Thanks. I tought it is a common problem and I can do in a 'simple' way